# Cannot find/install any Angular packages after update

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

Yesterday I upgraded Angular to `11.2.14`. I updated Angular with the Angular guide and used to command  `ng update @angular/cdk@11 @angular/cli@11 @angular/core@11 @angular/material@11`
After the command was executed it took a very long time to install the packages.

After 45minutes I canceled the `ng update` command and I wanted to try the install the packages manually with `npm install`. Unfortunately `npm install` wasn't working as I expected it to work.

`npm install` gives me the following error

```
npm ERR! While resolving: project-name@0.0.0        
npm ERR! Found: @angular/cdk@10.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!   @angular/cdk@"^10.2.7" from the root project
```

When I try `npm install @angular/cdk@11` I got the same error when I try `npm install`

I also get the same error on Angular material, core, common, compiler, and animations.
I've tried different node versions, clear npm cache, delete node modules and delete the package-lock.json.
None of those things seem to work.

The `package.json` Angular packages

```
"@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
"@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.4",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
"@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
"@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
"@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
```

Below is the output of ng --version. I know that the Angular CLI not at the same version is then Angular itself but even when Angular was 11.2.14 the errors still occure

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.14
Node: 14.17.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.0.5 (cli-only)
... common, core
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                             Version
-------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect           0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular       0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/core                11.2.14
@angular-devkit/schematics          11.2.14
@angular/animations                 <error>
@angular/cdk                        <error>
@angular/cli                        11.2.14
@angular/compiler                   <error>
@angular/compiler-cli               <error>
@angular/fire                       <error>
@angular/flex-layout                10.0.0-beta.32
@angular/forms                      11.2.14
@angular/language-service           11.2.14
@angular/localize                   11.2.14
@angular/material                   <error>
@angular/platform-browser           11.2.14
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic   11.2.14
@angular/router                     11.2.14
@schematics/angular                 11.2.14
@schematics/update                  0.1102.14
rxjs                                6.6.3 (cli-only)
typescript                          4.0.8
```

`npm install --force` or `npm install --legacy-peers` is not option because the packages wont be installed (and both commands are giving errors they can't find the Angular packges)

How can I resolve the error?

**update**
I've created a new project and copy paste the dependecies in the new package.json. After the `npm install` I got the same error. I believe the error occurs on global scope and not just the project scope.
I'm not sure how `Angular` gives `undefined`

`ng --version` global

```
Angular CLI: 12.0.5
Node: 14.17.1
Package Manager: npm 7.17.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: undefined
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1200.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.0.5 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.0.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.0.5 (cli-only)
```

**update**
It looks like Angular is adding a extra ´´´""´´´. Where does the extra ´´´""´´´ come from?

Comment: can u tried `ng update @angular/cdk` or `npm i @angular/cdk@11.2.13` ?

Comment: @naoval ```npm i @angular/cdk@11.2.13``` gives me the same error as ```npm i``` and ```ng update @angular/cdk``` gives me the error ```Package '@angular/cdk' is not a dependency.```

Comment: try removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`  `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` then run `npm i`

Comment: I would revert the change, and try it again, one after the other. Be aware that, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833316/ng-update-angular-core10-angular-cli10-isnt-working/67833317#67833317) changing your **global angular cli version** may help, explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67833317/11135174) how to do it .

Comment: @naoval I already tried that. It gives me the same error as before.